# Force a document to open in the application and not the web app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I have a large Excel file (under 1 meg, but almost 25 tabs) that none of my users can open in Excel Online. If you click on it in the document library, it spins for a while before giving this error:

> Request Was Taking Too Long | We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long.

Is there a way I can force this document to open in the native Excel application?

Comment: To clarify, I know how to open it in Excel by clicking the dots, then clicking the dots in the window that opens, then selecting "Edit in Excel." I want to save myself and my team the extra clicking.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to **Library Settings** -> **Advanced Settings** -> Check "**Open in the client application**"

**Edit:**

This opens all the documents in client application.

[image]

Comment: Note that this solution will affect the entire library, not just this one file, which may or may not be what ASTX813 wants.

Comment: Yeah, that is sort of a nuclear option, we really only have the one document that is problematic. Would this affect all documents on our sharepoint site, or just the document library for the given sub-site? And what does that do to users who don't have the client app installed?

Comment: It will affect only the particular library!

Comment: Still a pretty broad effect to accommodate a single file. Any more focused ways of forcing the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that if you encrypt a file with a password (distinct from workbook protection) then that file will not open in a browser. If a user attempts to open the workbook in a browser then a pop up will inform them that the file can only be opened in the Desktop App. The pop up even has a button to 'Open in Desktop App'.

This does not save users "extra clicks" as requested above, but it will prevent them from accidentally trying to launch the file in the browser causing it to hang. In my case it also prevents users from opening the file in a browser because doing so interferes with a Macro.

To find the workbook encryption option navigate to:
 File -> Info -> Protect Workbook -> Encrypt with Password